# Pearson correlation coefficent

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation, pearson-correlation

This question of mine is not tightly related to Matlab, but is relevant to it:
I'm looking how to fill in the matrix `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]` in a few nontrivial ways so that **as many places as possible** in

`corrcoef([a,b,c],[d,e,f])`

are zero. My attempts yield NaN result in most cases.

Comment: do you want absolutely zero correlation or are you looking for ways to generate both vectors such that on average their correlation is close to zero? do both vectors have length 3 as in your example or is the size variable? do you realize that the "as many places as possible" means exactly 2, since the diagonal elements will necessarily have a correlation of 1?

Comment: @sg1234 I want absolutely zero correlation. The length 3 is fine for me to imagine how the **defined** correlation 0 works for longer vectors. $n\geq 3$ is the minimum length obtained from exercise 4.6.9 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170959/students-t-nu-distribution). Yes I realize that **6** in various 9 places from 3x3 is maximum, am I right with $6=9-3$ here ? I just want to understand the notion when **Pearson sample correlation coefficient** is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the current comments, you are trying to understand how two series of random draws from two distributions can have zero correlation. Specifically, exercise [4.6.9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170959/students-t-nu-distribution) to which you refer mentions draws from two normal distributions.

An issue with your approach is that you are hoping to derive a link between a theoretical property and experimentation, in this case using Matlab. And, as you seem to have noticed, unless you are looking at specific degenerate cases, your experimentation will fail. That is because although the true correlation parameter rho in the exercise might be zero, a sample of random draws will always have some level of correlation. Here is an illustration, and as you'll notice if you run it the actual correlations span the whole spectrum between -1 and 1 despite their average being zero (as it should be since both generators are pseudo-uncorrelated):

```
n=1e4;
experiment = nan(n,1);
for i=1:n
    r = corrcoef(rand(4,1),rand(4,1));
    experiment(i)=r(2);
end
hist(experiment);
title(sprintf('Average correlation: %.4f%%',mean(experiment)));
```

If you look at the definition of Pearson correlation in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), you will see that the only way this can be zero is when the numerator is zero, i.e. E[(X-Xbar)(Y-Ybar)]=0. Though this might be the case asymptotically, you will be hard-pressed to find a non-degenerate case where this will happen in a small sample. Nevertheless, to show you you can derive some such degenerate cases, let's dig a bit further. If you want the expectation of this product to be zero, you could make either the left or the right hand part zero when the other is non-zero. For one side to be zero, the draw must be exactly equal to the average of draws. Therefore we can imagine creating such a pair of variables using this technique:

- we create two vectors of 4 variables, and alternate which draw will be equal to the average.
- let's say we want X to average 1, and Y to average 2, and we make even-indexed draws equal to the average for X and odd-indexed draws equal to the average for Y.
- one such generation would be: X=[0,1,2,1], Y=[2,0,2,4], and you can check that `corrcoef([0,1,2,1],[2,0,2,4])` does in fact produce an identity matrix. This is because, every time a component of X is different than its average of 1, the component in Y is equal to its average of 2.
- another example, where the average of X is 3 and that of Y is 4 is: X=[3,-5,3,11], Y=[1008,4,-1000,4]. etc.

If you wanted to know how to create samples from non-correlated distributions altogether, that would be and entirely different question, though (perhaps) more interesting in terms of understanding statistics. If this is your case, and given the exercise you mention discusses normal distributions, I would suggest you take a look at generating antithetic variables using the [Box-Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) transform.

Happy randomizing!

Comment: Finally someone has understood perfectly what I'm trying to do and `saved me`. If you are a good statistician you might be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170959/students-t-nu-distribution) which is going to be closed for unknown reasons.

Comment: @user2925716: if this answer “saved you”, the least you can do is upvote and accept.

Comment: @user2925716: thanks for the positive feedback. unfortunately, your original math question seems to be beyond my pedigree... as this seems to be sourced from a course, knowing what the chapter is about would give a clue as to which methods to use. Without knowing, my first approach, after perhaps breaking a few teeth on some brute force algebra, would probably be to look at the resulting characteristic function to see if it matches that of a Student distribution. If "characteristic functions" are discussed in that chapter then this would point strongly to this direction.

Comment: @sg1234 I would like to know yet (to indulge my curiosity) if there are **other** (short) vectors with defined zero Pearson correlation than those that has arisen of this type: as X average 1 alternating with Y average 2 ?

Comment: @user2925716 cf. formula: the numerator of the covariance is an expectation of a product, i.e. the value of each draw of X minus its average, times the value of each draw of Y minus its average (an expectation also includes a probability but I am assuming only events with proba>0, so the actual proba is irrelevant for finding a zero numerator). The only way the product can be zero is when one or both sides of the multiplication are zero. therefore there are many ways to construct such examples, but they all rely on this principle, afaict.

Comment: @sg1234 But cannot be it the case that some numbers are nonzero,say positive and some other non-zero but negative, so that the overall expectation kills to zero ??

Comment: @user2925716 once again, the formula really speaks for itself. Xbar is an average, the average of all Xs. That can be zero, but the LHS of the multiplication looks at the difference between X and Xbar. I feel like delving into probability is beyond the scope at this point, though perhaps this video will help... https://dlsun.github.io/probability/covariance.html once you understand that, then all we're saying is that we're making sure that when one side varies, the other is equal to zero, and vice versa.

Comment: @sg1234 The video points at the right direction, I've watched it carefully, but I cannot understand from it why on the **average** the contributions of (X-barX) with a different sign with (Y-barY) are smaller than those with the same signs?? Is the normality of X like N(barX,sigma) used in this conclusion? This is the last thing that I cannot carry out on my own.

Comment: @sg1234 Please have a look at this: ` corrcoef([0,0,2,2],[1,3,1,3])`. The resulting matrix **is** the identity matrix but it doesn't meet the alternating EX and EY property!

Comment: Yes that is what i called degenerate cases because very rarely will the sum be zero (of course it is the case here because of the symmetry). The alternating property requires no constraints on the sum since each product is zero. I think you are well off at this point and will leave you to figure out your needs, best.

Comment: @sg1234 Which **sum** do you mean,please ? Zero is the **value** of a R.V. X, no sum at all!

Comment: @user2925716 I really do not want to appear contemptuous or rude, but it really sounds to me like 1. you need a 101 course on probability and 2. this is not the place for math questions. An expectation, as I assumed you knew given that you were referencing an advanced statistics exercise, is a weighted sum. Over and out.